# Modelforms: matching query does not exist and post data

Tags: django

I have a field where the user chooses a vehicle's plate and according to this choice I want a form to be populated from a vehicles-table(query:`vehicle = Vehicles.objects.get(plate=plate)`).
I manage this with this view:

```
def vehicles_archive(request):
    user = request.user
    user_id = user.id 
    u_id = user_id

    vehicles = Vehicles.objects.filter(own_id1 = u_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        plate = request.POST.get('searchPlate')
        vehicle = Vehicles.objects.get(plate=plate)

        form = VehiclesForm(data=request.POST, instance=vehicle, own_id=u_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render_to_response('success.html', locals(), context_instance= RequestContext(request))
        else:
            vehicles = Vehicles.objects.filter(own_id1 = u_id)
            vehicle = Vehicles.objects.get(plate=plate)
            form = VehiclesForm(instance=vehicle, own_id=u_id)

    return render_to_response('vehiclesArchive.html', locals(), context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

All seems to work fine but when I edit a form-field and try to submit the form I get:
Vehicles matching query does not exist.
and it indicates the query with the plate.
There must be an error with the logic I use but how can I solve it?or is there a preferable way to achieve the above functionality?

Edit:

```
class Vehicles(models.Model):
    id = models.DecimalField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_digits=127, decimal_places=0)
    plate = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    tempflag = models.BooleanField()
    vht_id = models.ForeignKey('Vehtypes', null=True, db_column='vht_id',  blank=True)
    vlength = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=127, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    vwidth = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=127, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    vheight = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=127, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    vnetweight = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=127, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    vmaxload = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=127, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    axleno = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=127, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    chassis = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank=True)
    man_id = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturers', null=True, blank=True, db_column='man_id')
    own_id1 = models.ForeignKey('Owners', null=True, db_column='own_id1', related_name='veh_own_id1', blank=True)
    own_id2 = models.ForeignKey('Owners', null=True, db_column='own_id2',related_name='veh_own_id2', blank=True)
    ins_id = models.ForeignKey('Insurancecompanies', null=True, blank=True, db_column='ins_id')
    modelno = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank=True)
    checkflag = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.plate 

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'vehicles'
        ordering = ['plate']
```

while searchPlate is a random field rendered only for getting the users choice. The owners model definition is not important I think.

Comment: What is template? Is there `searchPlate` in POST data?

Comment: marlen your `if` control flow logic doesn't make sense. You check `if request.method == POST` although you ve already done it 6 lines above. Also you have a lot of code redundancy. Could you add your full model definitions about Vehicles and Owners?

Comment: yeah, I can sense that the prob is the two posts(with one post happens the same). I tried a redirect to another template with the plate as args and render the form in that template but with that solution the user can't change the plate once he chose for the first time. What else can I try?

Comment: What you need to do is fairly simple. If you post your model definitions it'll be easier to give you a solution. Also, on VehiclesForm you pass kwarg `own_id`. Is your form aware of this parameter?

Comment: @marlen, in that case your query for `vehicle` would fail as expected. You need to query for vehicle which has the plate `searchPlate`

Comment: @rantanplan I edited my question with the vehicles model definition. Yes the form is aware of the parameter.

Comment: @Rohan but the first time the user chooses a plate the query works and the form gets populated with the corresponding vehicle. The prob occurs when he edits and tries to submit the form.

Comment: @Rohan I think that u meant to ask if plate is in POST data. Yes plate  is there with value None after the form submission. But before the submission it has the value of the plate that the user chose because as I said the query works and the form gets populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I don't understand:

> I have a field where the user chooses a vehicle's plate

Where does this happen? In the view code you posted?

Because it seems like a 2 step process here, not one.

a) A user chooses from a list through `vehicles_archive` view. This view
only handles GET requests, since it is only for displaying the vehicles
this user owns. This view's url would be like `r'^vehicles/$'`.
And the list will be a set of entries, each one comprising of a link to the respective vehicle. e.g. `/vehicles/YKH4034/`. So we need another url regex in our urls.py
like `r'^vehicles/(?P<plate>\w{80})/$'`. And a different view handling this url.
Named for example `vehicles_archive_detail`.

b) The user chose the vehicle he wants to edit and now is served by the `vehicles_archive_detail`. This view handles both GET and POST requests.
GET for displaying the form for the specific vehicle and POST for when
the owner actually modifies(submits form) the vehicle.

I don't see this kind of logic on your code though. Or maybe I don't understand
your problem well enough.

**UPDATE:**

You don't need a GET parameter(searchPlate) neither a `search` button. It is not 
a form. Your vehicles_archive view will have a template similar to:

```
{% extends 'somebaseview.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <ul>
    {% for vehicle in owner_vehicles %}
        <a href="/vehicles/{{ vehicle.plate }}/"> {{ vehicle.plate }} </a>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

So the user will simply click on a link which will take him to the specific
vehicle he wants to edit.

**UPDATE 2:**

You say you need a dropdown menu and a search button. However I don't see the search
functionality. Is there a possibility that the form will not be found? Is there
a possibility that there will be more than one results(vehicles) when he "hits"
search?

In any case if that's what you really need. I see 2 ways:

1) Do all these things with Javascript and AJAX. Though it is hard for me
to display an example here, because it would be quite lengthy and out of
the scope of your original question.

2) Use django's [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) tool.

In any case you could start by making sure that the second step(user sees/edits specific vehicle) works, and then decide how to make the transition from step 1 to step 2. i.e.
Ajax or form wizard.

Comment: Seems legit, I like it. But when I try it, I choose a plate, hit search, the url becomes: ../vehiclesArchive/?searchPlate=KY123 but the view vehicles_archive_detail isn't being called(I also tried a simple print in it).what's wrong?

Comment: @marlen 1) I forgot to add a `$` to the first regex I provided. 2) See updated answer.

Comment: I noticed the $. Yeah ok it can work with links, but I needed (requested) a dropdown list with the plates from where the user would choose  one and by hitting search, the corresponding form would be rendered..

Comment: jquery and ajax is a solution I know, I just tried to avoid it, althougth I've used it. I'll check this form wizard tool cause I don't know it. Thank you for your time and your help in general! :)

Comment: @marlen Glad I helped. Also check the observations made by Chris Pratt. You should follow them unless you're dealing with a legacy database you have no control over.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're looking up a foreign key by its id instead of the object itself. For example with:

```
vehicles = Vehicles.objects.filter(own_id1 = u_id)
```

To compare against `own_id1`, you'd need to pass a `User` instance, not an integer. If you wanted to look it up by the id, then you'd need to do:

```
vehicles = Vehicles.objects.filter(own_id1_id = u_id)
```

This also illustrates why you shouldn't name a foreign key with `_id` in in its name. At the database level, Django automatically appends `_id`.

Comment: Actually it works with an integer too. But spot on about the bogus "_id"

Comment: I can't see how your answer is related to my question. Maybe you are right about the bad practice with the ids (but it is a legacy db) but the problematic query is the one with the plate and the query by itself is successful, the problem is in the whole logic i use with two forms in a view. But I kinda changed it now.